# Cobalt is it built under which architecture?

Tags: youtube, cobalt

Can someone help me understand cobalt architecture or give me some tutorials to learn ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the available documentation is at https://cobalt.dev, but you'll find some other helpful information in the [cobalt/doc](https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/refs/heads/master/src/cobalt/doc/) and [starboard/doc](https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/refs/heads/master/src/starboard/doc/) directories of the repository as well.